# Notification is not fired for each meeting in android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am developing a Client Meeting app in which user can store his upcoming meeting information. A notification about the meeting has to be fired 2 hours before the meeting time. But what happens is that the notification is fired only for the last meeting which is added. 
This may be happening because I am creating a `PendingIntent` with
`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.
Also using `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` does not help.
Adding a request code as mentioned in comment below does not help
Please provide a solution so that notification is fired for each meeting.

Thanks for help.

Code for `AlarmManager`:

```
private void setAlarm(int yyyy,int MM,int dd,int hh, String id){

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(yyyy, MM, dd, (hh-2), 0);

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0,new Intent(getActivity(), notify.class).putExtra("id", id), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
        //alarm.cancel(pending);    //read what happens with cancel
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pending);
    }
```

Code for `Notification`:

```
public class notify extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
            Datastore ds = new Datastore(context);
            SQLiteDatabase sql = ds.getReadableDatabase();
            Log.e("id in notify", id);
            Cursor curse= sql.rawQuery("SELECT NAME , CONTACT , DATE , TIME , ADDRESS , DETAILS FROM "+fields.table_name+" WHERE ID ='"+id+"' ", null);
            curse.moveToFirst();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id",id);
            bundle.putString("name", curse.getString(curse.getColumnIndex("NAME")));
            bundle.putString("contact", curse.getString(curse.getColumnIndex("CONTACT")));
            bundle.putString("date",curse.getString(curse.getColumnIndex("DATE")));
            bundle.putString("time", curse.getString(curse.getColumnIndex("TIME")));
            bundle.putString("address", curse.getString(curse.getColumnIndex("ADDRESS")));
            bundle.putString("details",curse.getString(curse.getColumnIndex("DETAILS")));


            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, finaldetails.class).putExtras(bundle),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

            Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setTicker("You have a meeting").setWhen(0)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Upcoming Meeting")
                    .setContentText("You have a meeting with "+bundle.getString("name"))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("You have a meeting"))
                    .setContentIntent(pending)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(001, notification);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, you are specifying the request id as zero for all the pending intents that you specify. To create individual alarms, you need to have different request codes for all the pending intents. Since it is the same, it is only considering the last alarm.

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0,new Intent(getActivity(), notify.class).putExtra("id", id), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```